# Docker Compose service is not using volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, azurite

I have this service...

```
storage:
 image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
 ports:
  "20000:10000"
 restart: unless-stopped
 volumes:
  C:/Data:/hello
```

I can add data to the Azurite service and I can browse it in the volume via Docker Desktop but I can't see any files in my local file system - the folder is always empty.

Why isn't the volume mapped to my file system?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotations in your volumes declaration since there are yaml special characters in local path.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. Below is a docker compose file where you can start `Azurite` with volumes. Please create a folder called `storagedata` at the same directory as your docker compose file exists.

```yaml
version: '3.4'
services:  
  
  storageemulator:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
    command: "azurite --loose --blobHost 0.0.0.0 --blobPort 10000 --queueHost 0.0.0.0 --queuePort 10001 --tableHost 0.0.0.0 --tablePort 10002 --location /workspace --debug /workspace/debug.log"
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"
      - "10001:10001"
      - "10002:10002"
    volumes:
      - ./storagedata:/workspace
```